# Applescript to open all InDesign files in a folder

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign, finder

I am trying to make a script which opens all InDesign files in a folder and edits them.

Currently trying to open the files, here is what I have:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
    open (every file of folder "test1" whose name ends with ".indd")
end tell
```

but I get a snytax error:

```
 Expected “,” but found “"”.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InDesign has no idea at all what files and folders are.

Only the `Finder` (and `System Events`) have knowledge about the file system

```
tell application "Finder" to set indesignFiles to (files of folder "test1" whose name extension is "indd") as alias list

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
    open indesignFiles
end tell
```

Consider that in the `Finder` the folder `test1` is a subfolder of the desktop folder.

Answer (score 3):

InDesign doesn't understand "every file of folder". The expression you are using is something you would say to the *Finder*.